# background color for primefaces menu does not work

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a template of primefaces, using css I have tried to place the color but the color comes out at the bottom of the center position, but in the p: menubar the color does not appear

with the background-color enabled
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSbWB.jpg

with the  background-color disabled
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrFBK.jpg

this is the template primefaces

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
   <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
     <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jsfcrud.css"/>
     <style type="text/css">
        .myLayoutStyleClass .ui-layout-unit-content   { 
            background-color: #D8D8DA;
     }

</style>   
</h:head>
<f:view>
<h:body>

    <p:layout fullPage="true">

<p:layoutUnit position="north" >  
  <h:graphicImage library="images" name="logo.jpg" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="headertags">
  <h:outputText id="h1" styleClass="h1Style" value="#{user.name}"/>
  <h:outputText id="h2" styleClass="h2Style"  value="Hora actual:  #{dialogBean.time}"/>
</h:panelGrid>      
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="center" styleClass="myLayoutStyleClass" >

        <ui:insert name="content"> 

            Página en construcción


            </ui:insert>

</p:layoutUnit> 

<p:layoutUnit position="south" >
<ui:insert name="footer">

</ui:insert>
</p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>

</h:body>
</f:view> 
</html>
```

If I try to apply the style in the index, the menu continues without color, no matter where and how the css class applies

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  >

<ui:define name="title">
<h:outputText value="Pagina Administrador"></h:outputText>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="menuForm" >

<p:menubar >
    <p:submenu label="Inicio" icon="ui-icon-home">
      <p:menuitem value="Matenimiento Clientes" outcome="clientes/ClienteList"/>
      <p:menuitem value="Matenimiento Vehiculos" outcome="vehiculos/VehiculoList"/>
      <p:menuitem value="Matenimiento Registros" outcome="registros/RegistroList"/>
      <p:menuitem value="Reporte Clientes" outcome="clientes/ClienteReport"/>  
      <p:menuitem value="Reporte Vehiculos" outcome="vehiculos/VehiculoReport"/>
      <p:menuitem value="Reporte Registros" outcome="registros/RegistroReport"/>
      <p:menuitem value="Configuracion Usuarios" outcome="usuarios/UsuarioList"/>   
      <p:menuitem value="Configuracion Grupos" outcome="grupos/GrupoList"/>
      </p:submenu> 
    <p:submenu label="Contraseña">
      <p:menuitem value="Cambiar Contraseña" outcome="usuarios/UsuarioChange"/>
    </p:submenu> 
    <p:submenu label="Salir">
     <p:menuitem value="logout" action="#{user.logout}"  />
    </p:submenu> 

</p:menubar> 

</h:form>    

</ui:define>

<ui:define name="footer">
<h:link outcome="/index" value="Regresar a la Pagina anterior"/>           
</ui:define>    

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: So it works if you don't use a p:layout? And I don't see any css for the menu

Comment: <h: head> I create the class. myLayoutStyleClass and I call it in <p: layoutUnit position = "center" styleClass = "myLayoutStyleClass">

Comment: That is about the layout!!! Your title states menu

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the background color only for the layout :

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .myLayoutStyleClass .ui-layout-unit-content   { 
        background-color: #D8D8DA;
 }
 </style>
```

You need to define a style class for your menubar :

```
<p:menubar styleClass="mymenubar" >
    ....
    .....
</p:menubar>
```

And customize the class on your css :

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .myLayoutStyleClass .ui-layout-unit-content   { 
        background-color: #D8D8DA;
      }
    .mymenubar .ui-menubar {
        background-color: #D8D8DA;
     }
   </style>
```